# want to parse href in ruby on rails using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am using [`nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) as my HTML parser.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td>Some Text</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <br />
            <a href="TransportRoom?servlet=CaseSearch.jsp&amp;advancedSearch=Advanced">
                Advanced Search
            </a>
            <br />
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this html code I want to parse the "Advance Search" link. This html is saved in variable named `doc1`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What output do you want? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer is working for me but if there is n number of links than we can manipulate it by this way

```
 html = Nokogiri::HTML(doc1)

 html.css("a").each do |element|
      if (element.text.strip == 'Advanced Search')
        advance_search_link = element.attr('href')
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be as simple as

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc1)
href = doc.css("a").first.attr('href')
```

This is what you want?

Comment: It will fatch first link but by manipulating i got my result Thanks mosch

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri.HTML <<-eotl
<html>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td>Some Text</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <br />
            <a href="TransportRoom?servlet=CaseSearch.jsp&amp;advancedSearch=Advanced">
                Advanced Search
            </a>
            <br />
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
eotl

@doc.at_xpath("//a[normalize-space(.)='Advanced Search']")['href']
# => "TransportRoom?servlet=CaseSearch.jsp&advancedSearch=Advanced"
```